# How to either read from one file or another in bash?

Tags: bash, list, compare, readfile

I have two files I am trying to read line by line, but I only want to continue reading from only file or the other on any given iteration of a loop. (I am also unsure how to check for EOF). Here is my pseudocode:

```
#initialize variables
line1=read <file1.txt
line2=read <file2.txt

#compare lists
while true
do
    #check if there is a match
    if [[ "$line1" == "$line2" ]]
    then
        echo match
        break
    elif [ "$line1" -lt "$line2" ]
    then
       line1=read <file1.txt    # <-SHOULD READ NEXT LINE OF F1
    else
       line2=read <file2.txt    # <-SHOULD READ NEXT LINE OF F2
    fi

    #Check for EOF
    if [[ "$line1" == EOF || "$line2" == EOF ]] 
    then
        break
    fi
done
```

Obviously, as it stands now, this would continue reading just the first line of F1 and F2.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe a duplicate? https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/26601/156990

Comment: I don't think so. Assuming my files were:
    File1.txt:
    A1
    A2
    A3
    
    File2.txt:
    B1
    B2
    B3

There are tons of results for reading two files in parallel i.e.

    A1
    B1
    A2
    B2
    A3
    B3

but I would like the ability to possibly get

    A1
    A2
    B1
    A3
    *exit*

or any other combination of orderings of lines from A and B...

Comment: `read` doesn't return or output a value (and if it did, the correct syntax would be `line1=$(read < file1.txt)`. Rather, it takes as an argument the name of the variable to assign a value to: `read line1 < file1.txt`

Comment: Aside: Are you trying to do a merge sort? `sort -m` will do that out-of-the-box.

Comment: btw, in addition to the syntax given in @chepner's answer (redirections at the bottom of a block, loop, or similar), you can also `exec 3<file1.txt 4<file2.txt` at the top of the file to set up redirections that persist until they're closed (ie. with `exec 3<&- 4<&-`) or the script exits.

Answer (score 1):

You need to open each file *once*, so that you don't reset the file pointer before each read. `read` will have a non-zero exit status any time it tries to read past the last line of a file, so you can check for that to terminate the loop.

```
{
  read line1 <&3
  read line2 <&4

  while true; do
    #check if there is a match
    if [[ "$line1" == "$line2" ]]; then
      echo match
      break
    elif [ "$line1" -lt "$line2" ]; then
      read line1 <&3 || break
    else
      read line2 <&4 || break
    fi
  done
} 3< file1.txt 4< file2.txt
```

Comment: `<3` vs `3<`? I think the syntax here is slightly off.